# Save an article or story on Drupal 7

Tags: 7, users

How can I save an article or story on Drupal 7?

Is there any modules to install, or do I need to do it programmatically?

**Note :** This is not offline bookmarks kind of stuff, nor is it related to browsers.

Comment: Are you looking some programmatic way to save nodes of type article/story?

Comment: I searching out for defined modules, so that we can install it easily.<br>And i got the a module called <a href="http://drupal.org/project/flag">Flag</a>, i just installed it and running successfull over D7.<br>By this way i am saving an article or story<br>And Can you let me know how to change the name of "Boomark this" to "custom name" after installing this module. <br>Thanks @ShoaibNawaz, Drupal Modules

Comment: Drupal already comes with per-installed module know as 'Node'. This module also covers all the api and callbacks to programmatically deal with contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your question and comments, you are looking [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.